# how to open up calendar's event creation screen using expo?

Tags: javascript, react-native, calendar, expo

I have tried `Calendar` API provided by Expo and created some events, but when I call `Calendar.createEventAsync(calendarId, details)` it just creates the event in the background and user doesn't have the opportunity to customize it, like adding some description or even hit the cancel button and prevent the process.
[image]
Actually I found the library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-add-calendar-event that works the same way as I described but it doesn't work with Expo.
so I wanted to ask if there is any way to implement the same functionality in an expo app?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is, check this link [expo calendar api](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/calendar/), you can create an event and delete it the similar to the library you found, this is a little example how to create an event

```
import * as Calendar from "expo-calendar"
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions"
```

after that, you will ask if the user will allow the application to access phone calendar or not

```
const [granted, setGranted] = useState(false)
const [eventIdInCalendar, setEventIdInCalendar] = useState("") 

const openCalendarRequest = async () => {
    const {status} = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CALENDAR)
    if (status === "granted") {
       setGranted(true)
    }
}

useEffect(()=>{
    openCalenarRequest() // Ask for Premission to access phone calendar
},[])
const eventDetails = {
    'Event Title', 
    startDate: new Date('2019-12-14 07:00'),
    endDate: new Date('2019-12-14 15:00'),
    }

const addEventToCalendar = async eventDetails => {
    const eventIdInCalendar = await Calendar.createEventAsync("1",eventDetails)
    Calendar.openEventInCalendar(eventIdInCalendar)// that will give the user the ability to access the event in phone calendar 
    setEventIdInCalendar(eventIdInCalendar)
   }
```

Then go and check your phone calendar

hope that helps.

Comment: OP asked for a library that displays a dialog before saving the event. Just like react-native-add-calendar-event. expo-calendar creates an event without displaying a dialog